# How much extra resin should put in my vat beyond what the slicer says that it needs?

Tags: slicing, resin

Starting with the premise that I that I can't just fill the vat to the brim (For example, because I don't have enough of a particular resin to do so), is there a rule of thumb, or a manufacturer's recommendation on how much resin I should put in my vat beyond the amount that my slicers says that it needs to print successfully, as a safety net against running the vat too low during the print due to uncured resin being retained on the surface of my model or inside a hollowed out model, and not freely floating in the vat?

For example, if I have a tank with XYZ dimension, and the slicer says that it needs 100ml of resin to completed, should I put in 150ml, 200ml, 300ml?, or percentage more ML based on the size of my vat?

I'm looking for the recommended minimum safety margin not to go below, not a maximum level.

Answer (score 3):

Your vat should have markings indicating a maximum level. Filling to the brim will result in a [Eureka moment](https://www.education.com/science-fair/article/Eureka-volume-displacement-water/), one much messier than the original bathtub version.

Consider that you want sufficient volume of resin to ensure that there will be some remaining on the vat when the build plate is lifted. Too little resin might result in areas of zero coverage. A low volume of resin may also affect how quickly the residual volume flows into the vacated area of the vat.

If you don't wish to use the max volume option of the vat (no markings? Check the manual) you could perform a test.

Pour resin to cover the vat surface. Use the manual controls to return the bed to home position. There will be some overflow on the build plate, but certainly not to exit the vat. Add enough resin to provide a few millimeters of coverage, then add the volume indicated by the slicer.

Most models are not solid blocks encompassing the entire area of the vat and as the build plate lifts, less resin will be required to cover the tapering portions of the model, ensuring better coverage than a minimum.

Comment: I think that you've misunderstood the question, in looking for the minimum level, not the maximum level.

Comment: Your minimum level would be a few millimeters to ensure the surface of the vat is covered, perhaps a bit more for insurance, plus the volume specified by the slicer, perhaps a bit more for insurance, as described in the fourth paragraph.